# How to build a non active branch with a build definition?

Tags: tfs, branch, build-definition

**My project :** One dev branch, multiple version branch.

**I have :** One build definition to build the main branch with test and one for create the production without test.

**What I tried to do :** I cloned my second Build definition, renamed it, changed the sln path on the process property and executed it manually to build a production version. The branch was created after passing all the test on the main (dev) branch

**What's the result :** "Exception Message: There is no working folder mapping for $/autocompletion/path_to/non_dev_branche/project.sln. (type ItemNotMappedException)"

I searched how to make the branch as a working folder (and if it's possible) without any result. The path was created by VS 2012, I just selected the file.

[image: My process page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the build definition's workspace mappings. It should be on the tab named *Parametres de la source*. If it's not there, it'll be on one of the other tabs.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this works fine ! I forgot to change the path of the other branch to the current one.